# Как определить синтаксически неделимое словосочетание?

Tags: подлежащее

Я что-то путаюсь с определением  синтаксически неделимого словосочетания выступающего в предложении  подлежащим. Особенно когда в словосочетании, нередко, допускается вставка других членов предложения.

*Около полудня обыкновенно появляется **множество** круглых высоких **облаков**.* (Тургенев)

По какому признаку можно понять что в предложении есть неделимое словосочетание, выступающее подлежащим? 
Спасибо.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что вопрос взят из Интернета, и на него уже есть ответ. https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/701-12_podlezhaschee.html

Comment: Зачем вы берете готовые вопросы из Интернета и задаете их здесь? Нас проверяете?

Comment: А вот зачем  - чтобы узнать не правило  только но и его  детальное описание. Помогает, знаете ли.... http://fb.ru/article/392258/nedelimyie-slovosochetaniya-eto-chto-takoe

Comment: Вам, Серж, не модератором нужно стремиться быть, но вникать в суть вопроса. Все больше пользы будет. (Если есть что сказать) Имхо

Comment: А вот и результат моих изысканий http://joxi.ru/4AkQGNXSyPwYXm  как видите не зря.... Жаль не благодаря Вам

Comment: Wighn, а я и не стремлюсь быть модератором. Это раз. Во-вторых, на том сайте, с которого вы вязали задание, все подробно и ясно описано. И , в -третьих, как вы думаете, почему никто не ответил на ваш вопрос?

Comment: А вот и ответили!

Comment: А что ответили? То же, что написано на том сайте.

Answer (score 1):

***Около полудня обыкновенно появляется множество круглых высоких облаков...*** (Тургенев)

Подлежащее ***множество облаков*** выражено синтаксически неделимым (цельным) словосочетанием с количественным значением; главное слово (существительное ***множество***) стоит в форме именительного падежа.